# Finding a counterexample - bounedness of one function implies monotone

Tags: calculus

I need to find a counterexample to the following claim, and can't find one. Will be happy if someone will be able to help me out:

> If $f(x)$ is monotone increasing such that $g(x)\leq f(x) \leq g(x)+\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x>1$, then there exists $N>1$ such that $g(x)$ is monotone increasing in $(N,\infty)$.

Thank you!

Comment: $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, $g(x)=x$ if $x$ is an integer and $x-\frac1 x$ otherwise. $g(n+\frac 1 {2n}) <g(n)$ in this case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you!